# Unit testing with Mockitos not working as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new with Mockito and I wanted to write a unit test for some legacy code. I did try few techniques mentioned for using mockito while testing my specific scenario but I am not able to find a solution to my usecase. Here is my scenario :

I have a method A( does local processing of data) and a method B (does some remote processing of data). Method A in turn calls my method B. I want to call method A and when it in turn calls method B, then I want to return a predefined value from method B, lets says a list of files. Here is the sample code from Test class and actual class:

```
Myclass mc = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
when(mc.methodB(param1,param2)).thenReturn(fileSet); // returns mocked fileSet (set of files)
when(mc.methodA(param1,param2)).thenCallRealMethod();  //calls real method A
mc.methodA(param1,param2); //does not return the mocked value from methodB

class MyClass{
   public Set<File> methodB(param1,param2){
        //some processing
        return fileSet;
   }

   public void methodA(param1,param2){
        //some processing
        Set<FileSet> fileSet = methodB(param1,param2);
       //some more processing on returned files
   }

}
```

I created a mock of my class and made sure that when I invoke method A, real method call for method A happens and when I invoke method B, mock results are returned.

If I test method A and method B separately it works but when I call method A which in turn calls method B, it does not return my mocked value from method B.

Is this not the right way of doing this call or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to mock one method from a class while really calling another method from the same class.

This can be done using [spies](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13): with spies, every method from the object is really called, unless it was explicitely stubbed:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
MyClass spy = spy(myClass); // creates a spy for myClass
doReturn(new HashSet<File>() {{ add(new File("file1")); }}).when(spy).methodB("", ""); // stubbing method B
spy.methodA(param1, param2); // calling the real method A
```

Note that spies should be used carefully, only to deal with legacy code that you cannot change.

Note that the construct to stub `methodB` differs from the "usual" construct. If we write the following code:

```
when(spy.methodB("", "")).thenReturn(...);
```

what is happening is that the real `methodB` is getting actually called right here, and this is something we do not want. In the second construct:

```
doReturn(...).when(spy).methodB("", "");
```

the `methodB` is not called.

Here's a complete test class demonstrating spies:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        MyClass spy = spy(myClass); // creates a spy for myClass
        doReturn(new HashSet<File>() {{ add(new File("file1")); }}).when(spy).methodB("", ""); // stubbing method B
        spy.methodA("", ""); // calling the real method A
    }

}

class MyClass {

    public Set<File> methodB(String param1, String param2) {
        return new HashSet<File>() {{ add(new File("file2")); }};
    }

    public void methodA(String param1, String param2) {
        Set<File> fileSet = methodB(param1, param2);
        System.out.println(fileSet); // prints [file1] and not [file2], meaning the stubbed method was called and not the real one
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I want to test methodA which in turn is calling methodB. I want to call the real method A and when internally it calls methodB, it should return the mocked value of fileSet. I did try with your approach but it still makes a call to actual method instead of giving the mocked value. Any ideas??

Comment: I also noticed that that when I am making the stub, i.e.  when(spy.methodB(param1, param2)).thenReturn(fileSet)  and run the method, it goes into the actual method call. I was not expecting that to happen when I create a stub. Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: I did try this but my problem is this line: when(spy.methodB("", "")).thenReturn(new HashSet<File>() {{ add(new File("file1")); }}); so when it try to create stub of method B , I can see in debug logs that it is actually making call to that method when I run the test. I was not expecting this to happen. But when I do the same thing with just mocking the class (not spy) and stubbing by adding the when and then it works without making call to the method. I am not sure why the call to actual method is made when we are trying to stub it out. Is this normal?

Comment: @Shyna You are correct and I made a mistake in my code. See my edit.

Comment: So when I try it in my actual usecase it does not work. i.e method A calling method B. But, if I try to do methodB standalone like I was doing before it works. I am not sure why it fails to call the stubbed version of methodB when I say spy.methodA ? If I just test methodB, it gives me the stubbed results which brings me back to the original problem. I was able to do the same thing using simple mock but it fails in when a real method needs to call a subbed version. I am not sure if it is possible or there is something that needs to be done in a different manner?

Comment: @Shyna I'm not sure I understand. The class I have posted in my answer makes a call to the real methodA and then calls the stubbed methodB successfully.

Comment: In my case when I place this in my actual code it does not call the mock method but instead it calls the actual method. I am doing everything the way you have mentioned still for some reason I do not get the mock result from methodB. Could it be possible that the params that I am sending in method B might be not be the same as I am stating in the stubbed version and that is why it does not call it? Since I cannot think of anything else I am guessing this could be probable cause. Any thoughts?

Comment: I did check the params too and they are same as well. I am not sure if there could be anything else that I might be missing.

Comment: I guess the key to this was not using when then and instead use do Return. I was doing something wrong.